# What is the maximum number of features in Logistic Regression Problem

Tags: logistic, natural-language, tf-idf

I was doing Text classification(binary) hosted on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-insincere-questions-classification) with approx 1.3 millions observations.

My approach is to use Logistic Regression after computing the TF-IDF matrix with n-grams = 1:3.

With this approach the number of feature is going to sky rocket.

Is there any limit to the number of features that can be used in the logistic regression?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the glm function in R, or is this a conceptual question about the limits of logistic regression itself?

Comment: I am thinking to use glm function from R but its a conceptual question. Edited the question accordingly.